# Why is %s faster than %d for integer substitution in python?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am going through the examples mentioned [here](http://pythonfasterway.uni.me/), and am looking at [this example](http://pythonfasterway.uni.me/#test11). I ran a sample example below on ipython, and the result is consistent, i.e., `"%d"` is slower than `"%s"`:

```
In [1]: def m1():
   ...:     return "%d" % (2*3/5)

In [2]: def m2():
   ...:     return "%s" % (2*3/5)

In [4]: %timeit m1()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 529 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit m2()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 192 ns per loop

In [6]: from dis import dis

In [7]: dis(m1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('%d')
              3 LOAD_CONST               5 (6)
              6 LOAD_CONST               4 (5)
              9 BINARY_DIVIDE       
             10 BINARY_MODULO       
             11 RETURN_VALUE        

In [9]: dis(m2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('%s')
              3 LOAD_CONST               5 (6)
              6 LOAD_CONST               4 (5)
              9 BINARY_DIVIDE       
             10 BINARY_MODULO       
             11 RETURN_VALUE
```

Both the code blocks are similar, and even the output of disassembler is same, so why is `"%s"` faster than `"%d"`?

Comment: It must obviously be the overloaded implementation BINARY_MODULO, not that that is any explanation ;-)  Unrelatedly.. when did Python start doing constant folding (`2*3`)?

Comment: I'm not sure why the difference is there, but what's making the difference in time is not happening inside the python bytecode, but in the implementation of the modulo operator, which probably happens in C. If I'm not mistaking, that's why it doesn't show up in the disassembly.

Comment: Just a note: the difference between the two occurs inside the modulus operator, so it won't appear in the bytecode of the function that uses that operator.

Comment: Perhaps this is related: http://bugs.python.org/issue5176 (you'll get to the actual code from there anyways..)

Comment: Anyway, I assume `%d` is slower because it has to do more work.  Both have to convert the data to a string, but `%d` also has to check the sign, possibly round the number, etc.

Comment: maybe you could find your answer by checking the source http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/stringobject.c?view=markup go to line 4219 `PyString_Format(PyObject *format, PyObject *args)`

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that [the link you gave](http://pythonfasterway.uni.me/) is atrocious and you should for the large part ignore it completely.

Comment: @Veedrac Atrocious it definitely is; I ran equivalents for all the examples there and while many ignore conventions and introduce extra statements, some other results (15, 22 etc) are simply incorrect. This one however worked as written, hence the question..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was discussed in [hacker news](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8814036), I am just formatting @nikital answer for SO:

The function `PyString_Format` in [`Objects/stringobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a5c7a4257507a77699a1ab8ec079f41d505b9eee/Objects/stringobject.c#L4444) does the formatting for the `%` operator. For `%s` it calls `_PyObject_Str` which in turn calls `str()` on the object. For `%d` it calls `formatint` (located in the same file).

The `str()` implementation for ints is in `int_to_decimal_string` in ([`Objects/intobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a5c7a4257507a77699a1ab8ec079f41d505b9eee/Objects/intobject.c#L1172))  and it's incredibly simple:

```
do {
    *--p = '0' + (char)(absn % 10);
    absn /= 10;
} while (absn);
```

The code for `formatint` is way more complex, and it contains two call to the native snprintf:

```
PyOS_snprintf(fmt, sizeof(fmt), "%s%%%s.%dl%c",
              sign, (flags&F_ALT) ? "#" : "",
              prec, type);
// ...
PyOS_snprintf(buf, buflen, fmt, -x);
```

The native `snprintf` is heavier because it handles precision, zero-padding and stuff like that.

I believe this is why `%d` is slower. `%s` is a straight "divide-by-10-and-subtract" loop while `%d` are two library calls to the full-blown `sprintf`. However I didn't actually profile the code because I don't have a debug build, so I might be completely wrong.

Comment: Ahhhh! I found the link for the website in the hacker news newsletter today, should've looked in the forums as well. Anyway, thanks and +1.